# Way to always display question while browsing answers

Tags: feature-request

I think it would be useful to be able to always see the question while browsing answers. This is because many times answers will reference specific details in the question, so scrolling back and forth between the two is a little inconvenient.

Comment: Could probably do that with a greasemonkey script.

Comment: How, specifically, do you propose making the question always visible when viewing answers?

Comment: some CSS to fix the question at the top after scrolling past it, also it could be optional, with a checkbox to opt to turn it on....EDIT: if a question is too long, then perhaps that would have its own scroll bar.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, i didn't know about such a thing, pretty neat, but still would be more convenient to have it be a feature

Comment: What if the question is a bit longer?

Comment: hmmm.... I've seen more than one question that don't fit on the browser. How do I look at the answer then?

Comment: As i clarified in my edit, the questions that are very long could have their own scroll bar

Comment: Personally I don't care about viewing the question while *reading* an answer, but I would like this for when I'm *writing* an answer. Right now I find myself opening the question in a separate tab or sometimes even temporarily copying large portions of the question in to the answer box so I can see them side-by-side. Ideally I would like, perhaps, an optional scrolling div that I can expand/collapse at will so it's not mandatorily in the way.

Comment: Also, on a really wide screen, there is a lot of wasted space, as the actual content only takes up 1/3 of the space. The currently empty space could be used for this.